# React async timing issue, cause modal to pop up with prefilled form after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a setCurrentProject call using useState, useEffect hooks api but the modal pops up before the state has been set and it causes the data to throw an error or be blank if i throw in a conditional to check if it's there.

How do I make sure the state changes before the modal opens with the correct prop data

```
const EditProjectModal = ({modalOpen, handleClose, addTask, currentProject}) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
    const [projectTasks, setProjectTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setName(currentProject.name)
        setProjectTasks(currentProject.tasks)
        setStartDate(currentProject.startDate)
        setEndDate(currentProject.endDate)
    }, [currentProject])

    return(
        <Modal
        centered={false}
        open={modalOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
        >
            <Modal.Header>Edit Project</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group widths="equal">

                        <Form.Field
                            control={Input}
                            label="Project" 
                            placeholder="Enter the name of your project..."
                            required 
                            value={name}
                            onChange={handleName}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group widths='equal'>

                        <Form.Field required>
                            <label>Start Date</label>
                            <DatePicker 
                                selected={startDate}
                                onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
                                selectsStart
                                startDate={startDate}
                                endDate={endDate}
                            />
                        </Form.Field>

                        <Form.Field required>
                            <label>End Date</label>
                            <DatePicker 
                                selected={endDate}
                                onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
                                selectsEnd
                                startDate={startDate}
                                endDate={endDate}
                                minDate={startDate}
                                placeholderText="Select end date.."
                            />
                        </Form.Field>

                    </Form.Group>

                    <ProjectTasksContainer projectTasks={projectTasks} setProjectTasks={setProjectTasks}/>

                    <Divider hidden/>

                    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
                </Form>
            </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
```

I've left out some of the change functions etc because that's not important to the state change.

It's being triggered by a button from another component

```
const handleEdit = () => {
        setCurrentProject(project)
        handleEditProjClick();
    }
```

edited to add dashboard that uses the editProjectModal

```
const Dashboard = ({notes, setNotes, tasks, setTasks, goals, setGoals, projects, setProjects}) => {
    //============== STATE VARIABLES ===================//
    const [projModalOpen, setProjModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [editProjModalOpen, setEditProjModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [currentProject, setCurrentProject] = useState({});

    //============== MODALS ===================//

    const handleProjModalOpen = () => {
        setProjModalOpen(true);
    }

    const handleProjModalClose = () => {
        setProjModalOpen(false);
    }

    const handleEditProjModalOpen = () => {
        setEditProjModalOpen(true);
    }

    const handleEditProjModalClose = () => {
        setEditProjModalOpen(false);
    }

    //============== RENDERING FUNCTION ===================//
    return (
        <Fragment>
                    <Grid columns={2}>
                        <Grid.Row stretched>

                            <Grid.Column width={12}>

                                <Container style={{width: "90%"}}>
                                    <Segment basic>
                                        <Segment textAlign="right">
                                            <ProjectButton handleClick={handleProjModalOpen}/>
                                            <ProjectModal handleClose={handleProjModalClose} modalOpen={projModalOpen} addTask={addTask} addProject={addProject} />
                                            <EditProjectModal handleClose={handleEditProjModalClose} modalOpen={editProjModalOpen} addTask={addTask} currentProject={currentProject} />
                                        </Segment>

                                </Container>

                            </Grid.Column>

                            <Grid.Column width={4}>
                                <Segment>
                                    <ProgressContainer projects={projects} handleProjClick={handleProjModalOpen} handleEditProjClick={handleEditProjModalOpen} setCurrentProject={setCurrentProject}/>
                                </Segment>
                            </Grid.Column>

                        </Grid.Row>
                    </Grid>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

the parent holds the setCurrentProject state and passes it down to that child and also passes down the handleEditProjClick();

What's the best way to handle this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide more information on where the EditProjectModal is rendered and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it's being rendered in a parent component. I just want to set the currentProject to the id from the edit button clicked. It all works - the problem i am having is that i want the form to prefill with the current project data, and it's not waiting for the async setState to finish

Comment: I don't think you need an `effect` for this - why don't you just set the initialValues in `useState`?

Comment: Where is the code that uses the `EditProjectModal`?

Comment: added dashboard that uses it and sets current project

Comment: @dpdenton effect is needed because the whole app is functional components and using hooks. They aren't trying to rerender unless the dependency changes bc the state that changes is not in the same component

Comment: why can you not do 
    const [name, setName] = useState(currentProject.name); ?

Comment: @AlexanderHemming the functional component is rendered earlier and no state changes inside of it. just the state of the prop being passed to it.

Comment: where is handleName()? Shouldn't that handle changes? You could start them all as an empty string if the change loads so quickly the user likely won't see an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `editProjModalOpen` and `currentProject` are independent you could get a situation where `editProjModalOpen` is `true` and  `currentProject` is `{}` - you'd need to account for that, e.g. `{!isEmpty(currentProject) && <EditProjectModal ... /.>}`

This would then guarantee `currentProject` is set in `EditProjectModal` and you could just set the initial values in state off the `currentProject`:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(currentProject.name);
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(currentProject.startDate);
```

Or if you have to `useEffect` then just check the state before rendering the modal:

```
if (!name ) {
   return null
}
```

Comment: i checked the reverse with Object.keys(currentProject).length === 0 || <EditProjectModal  /> and this worked thank you for your help!

Comment: what is best practice? or is there not really one?

Comment: i was also able to make it work by adding an additional function and adding async and await and then able to useEffect as normal without any checks but im guessing that's not the best solution